# Make a query to display unmatched data

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

I m having difficulty making a query that displays unmatched data in between 2 tables.
The tables are:

```
Employee data                   Salary data
ID  Holidays               ID      Holiday
1    10                    0       10
2     8                    1        5
3     5                    2        8
4     7                    3        5
5     8                    7        6
6     5                    8        9
7     6                    9        2
8     9                    10       3
```

the primary key is ID for both tables.

I want my query result to contain all the values that does not match in both tables.
The type of output i want is something like this:

```
ID    Holiday
0       10
1       10
1        5
4        7 
5        8
6        5
9        2
10       3
```

I tried using unmatched query wizard but that only compares ID, not the Holiday column.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a union of two exists queries:

```
SELECT ID, Holiday FROM Employee as e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Salary as s WHERE s.ID = e.ID AND s.Holiday = e.Holiday)
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Holiday FROM Salary as s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employee as e WHERE e.ID = s.ID AND e.Holiday = s.Holiday);
```

Comment: A Holiday condition is also needed in the subqueries.

Comment: @jarlh Right you are.  And now, we have to wait to see if Access' peculiar syntax will allow this query to even run.

Comment: SQL statement is not correct.Please use delete,insert, procedure,select,update.